# What is fdisk o option for?

Tags: partition, hard-disk, fdisk

When partitioning a hard drive with fdisk , the o option help says "create a new empty dos partition table".

what does this do actually..?

Comment: as quick info not answer ! it will erase the old table (files will not be erased but LOST o.O) , you'll have an empty hard drive ready to be partitionned !

Answer (score 2):

There's 2 types of partition tables commonly found on PC's: DOS (the traditional kind) and GPT (the newer, slightly less compatible kind). The `o` option will nuke your partition table, destroying all of your partition definitions. This can be useful if it's corrupted or you just want to start fresh with your disk.